# Append pattern to a string in a table only for entries with a pattern

Tags: sql, string, oracle

my problem is that i want to append "%@" to an attribute in an Oracle table only for entries with this pattern -> not "%@%"

With:

```
select t.* from myTable t where t.email not like '%@%';
```

I get the entries

Responses i.e.:

```
google.com 
test.com
amazon.com
```

this should be replaced to

```
%@google.com
%@test.com
%@amazon.com
```

Any ideas or hints?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Your UPDATE query would look this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET email="%@" || email WHERE  email not like '%@%';
```

Comment: Hello,  the select select t.* from myTable t where t.email not like '%@%';   works fine and that is what I want under the PL/SQL developer.

Comment: Ok, then just remove the backslash from the query.

Comment: But thanx a lot email="%@" || email was the hint that i needed :-)